# Receiving JavaScript Error on WebPage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Error is:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; CMNTDF; .NET4.0C)

Timestamp: Thu, 7 Mar 2013 12:39:19 UTC

Message: Function expected
Line: 1
Char: 36223
Code: 0

URI: http://www.amleo.com/Javascript/jqueryplugins.js

Any ideas as to what it means / how I can fix?

Comment: It means "Your code has been minified, use a non-minified version to debug this"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a call to `Function` where it should be `function` just crtl-f it. Next time, don't post a minified version. Pretty much no one is going to want to sift through a minified version of your js, nor should we have to...